# lock the iphone for limited amount of time

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on an application in which I want to set the password that locks the phone for a limited amount of time. While the password is set, the phone is locked except for sending or receiving phone calls to emergency numbers or user selected numbers in the application.

The phone is unlocked either when the time expires or when we enters the password.

My question is that is it possible ?

Comment: Not Possible dude...sorry

Comment: Not possible. Why make an app like that? The functionality you are describing is already in the phone (expect the "unlock when the time expires" - feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible on a vanilla iOS device. Maybe with a jailbreak.

May I ask why you want to create an app like that? The phone's lock works almost like that already?